# getting data between particular tags in html

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, html-parsing

I want get the data between particular tags from html data.

```
<ul>    
    <li>
        More consistent tension control and approximation with each pass than with traditional sutures.
        <ul>                    
            <li>Unique anchor designs provide multiple points of fixation along the device, allowing tension on the device to be maintained during closure.<sup><a class="reference_link" href="#22">[22]</a></sup></li>
            <li>Compared to traditional sutures, STRATAFIX™ Devices enable surgeons to easily manage tension and control approximation with each pass.<sup><a class="reference_link" href="#3">[3]</a></sup></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Here, i want get the data from `<a class="reference_link" href="#3">[3]</a>` i want to store that value (eg.3).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are relevant sources on the internet on how to parse HTML on iOS; e.g. http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios:

> [...] there is a handy little library that’s included in the iOS SDK called libxml2.

The article seems to have code examples on how to achieve exactly what you want, as far as I can understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could use python to parse the html page using Beautiful Soup module.

Here is a link to it - http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

this has some sample code that you can follow.
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/beautifulsoup-4-python/

Comment: I suspect the question had the "ios" and "objective-c" tags attached to it, which makes me think Python would not be of much help here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JQuery it may useful for you..

```
 var items = $('#listTable li sup');
```

Here listTable is listview id.

Comment: the question was about Objective C and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

try beautiful soup 
here is the code

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/')
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    link1 = link.get('href') 
    print link1
```

This is the case if you are using python as coding language. You will get all links present in the document with this.
Here is the link for beatifulsoup documantation :

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/